# Why does text overlap using react-graph-vis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-graph-vis

[image]
Hi
Could you please tell me Why text overlap using react + graph ?I am using this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-graph-vis

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-stallman-7h61c

When data is transfer bidirectional then text is overlap ?

```
{ from: 1, to: 2, label: "asdas asd" },
      { from: 2, to: 1, label: "xcc ashdhashd" },
```

any update ?

Comment: Looks like that’s how the library is built

Comment: ohh .. will i use another library

Comment: any update ? in this

Comment: That is your decision. Use another library if this one doesn’t fit your needs

Comment: do you know any library which have these features

Comment: i searched a lot but not found another lib

Comment: please suggest any library

Comment: is this library is licensed `react-gojs`